# remove 3 directories in url via htaccess file

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to convert the URL http://localhost/project1/mvc/public/content/1 to the URL http://localhost/content/1.

I have my .htaccess file placed in the **public** folder that removes the index.php in the URL.

```
 Options -MultiViews
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteBase /project1/mvc/public
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Here's my directory structure:

```
Project 1
---mvc
-----app
-----public
```

I need help in the creating .htaccess file for this. What is the syntax for modifying the URL and which folder/s should I put the .htaccess file/s?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file (above a directory level of `mvc`):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^((?!/project1/mvc/public/).*) project1/mvc/public/$1 [L,NC]
```

Comment: i placed the .htaccess file outside the project1 folder and it worked. thanks anubhava!